# Column ordering bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap layout like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
    1
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
    2
    </div>  
    <div class="col-md-2">
    3
    </div>
</div>
```

It looks like this:

1 2 3

On mobile device, column 1 is on top, which is what I want, but then I want 3 column to appear the second and then 2 column to be third.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the classes defined by bootstrap (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/#order) like below

```css
.row > div {
 border:2px solid;
 text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 order-0 order-md-0">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 order-2 order-md-1">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 order-1 order-md-2">
      3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In Bootstrap 4 grids are done with Flexbox, so you can use `order`

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .col-md-2 {
        order: 1;
    }
    .col-md-8 {
        order: 2;
    }
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/o4ab1wrq/

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/order